# elevated diskpart output

Tags: winapi, python-3.x, runas

I need to run diskpart in my python3 script under Windows 7 and capture its output. I run the script in elevated mode; it runs but I can't capture the output and thus can't determine if it was successful. Here's its invocation:

win32api.ShellExecute(0, runas, diskpart, /s C:\TEMP\mapRHD.dp > C:\TEMP\diskpart.out, C:\Python3, 1)

The C:\TEMP\diskpart.out file doesn't get written.

I didn't really think that the redirection "> C:\TEMP\diskpart.out" would work here but I don't know what else to do. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirection with '>' is shell syntax that instructs the shell how to direct the standard output stream of the created process. diskpart doesn't understand it. You can run the command via the shell (whatever `COMSPEC` is) with the '/c' option. This should work:

```
import os
import win32api

shell = os.environ['COMSPEC']  # e.g. cmd.exe
command = r'/c diskpart /s C:\TEMP\mapRHD.dp > C:\TEMP\diskpart.out'
win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'runas', shell, command, '', 1)
```

**Edit:**

To get the return code from diskpart, it's  simpler to restart your script as an elevated process, as above. The script name is in `__file__`, and run `sys.executable`. On start, check `win32com.shell.shell.IsUserAnAdmin()` for elevated privileges. If the process is elevated, run diskpart with `output = subprocess.check_output(r'diskpart /s C:\TEMP\mapRHD.dp')`. You can post-process and log the output as desired.

If the command fails to execute, an `OSError` is raised. If diskpart exits with an error, `subprocess.CalledProcessError` will be raised, which has the `returncode` as an attribute.

A more complicated approach is to use [`win32com.shell.shell.ShellExecuteEx`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/shell__ShellExecuteEx_meth.html), which returns a handle to the new process. By keyword, set `fmask = win32com.shell.shellcon.SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`, `nShow = win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL` (or whichever show level you need), `lpVerb = 'runas'`, `lpFile = os.environ['COMSPEC']`, and `lpParameters = command`. You need the value of the `hProcess` key (the process handle) from the dict it returns.

Then use [`win32event.WaitForSingleObject`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32event__WaitForSingleObject_meth.html) to wait for the process to close. To wait indefinitely use `win32event.INFINITE`. Finally, call [`win32process.GetExitCodeProcess`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/pywin32/win32process__GetExitCodeProcess_meth.html) to get the exit code. As is, I think running via the shell means this code will either be 0 (success) or 1 (fail), but you could maybe get around that by appending `command += " & exit /b %%errorlevel%%"`.

Comment: A related question... Is there any way to get the Error Code returned by the original (i.e. diskpart) command?

Comment: Thank you eryksun... The process sounds more trouble than it is worth. I've noted it and may yet try it if I need it.