# win32print determine when printing has finished

Tags: python, winapi

I have found [this](https://github.com/mwhit74/practice_examples/blob/577578edd958609faca2a078ff3e8d1a38206233/printPDFfiles.py) code demonstrating
printing with win32print. There is a call of

`time.sleep(5)`
.

How can I better determine when the printer is printing and when printing has finished,
to notify the user about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18030622/3694381 From here it says that shellexecute doesn't give any info about the process. Maybe you can use StartDocPrinter and then GetJob api of win32print

Comment: Zero prospects of making this work. The entire approach is wrong. You'll need to do the printing from your process.