# How print Document in order using python?

Tags: python, winapi, win32com, printers, shellexecuteex

I am using **`win32api`** **`python`** package for printing document. I have two different folders on the basis of print type. Folder 1 for **single side print** and Folder 2 for **double side print**. That was obtained by win32api package but the problem is **sequential print**.

`attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex` is used for setting printing mode. **1 is for single side** and **2 for dobule side.** which are eventually folder names.

**`win32api.ShellExecute(0,'print',file_path,'.','/route',0)`** printing documents but not in sequence.

So I followed other [SOLUTION FROM HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025882/how-to-determine-if-win32api-shellexecute-was-successful-using-hinstance).
Which is giving me this error

```
shell.ShellExecuteEx(fmask = win32com.shell.shellcon.SEE_MASK_NOASYNC, lpVerb='print', lpFile=file_path, lpParameters=name)
NameError: name 'win32com' is not defined
```

Code is as follow

```
import win32api
import win32print
import os
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435973/print-pdf-file-in-duplex-mode-via-python
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025882/how-to-determine-if-win32api-shellexecute-was-successful-using-hinstance                              
Base_Path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

name = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
print("------Base_Path-->",Base_Path,"-----")
print("-----GetDefaultPrinter--->",name,"-----")

for folder in "12":

    src = os.path.join(Base_Path, "admin", folder)
    for file in sorted(os.listdir(src)):
        file_path = os.path.join(src, file)
        print("------",file_path,"-----")
        printdefaults = {"DesiredAccess": win32print.PRINTER_ALL_ACCESS}
        handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(name, printdefaults)
        level = 2
        attributes = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, level)
        attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex
        attributes['pDevMode'].Duplex = int(folder)
        win32print.SetPrinter(handle, level, attributes, 0)
        win32print.GetPrinter(handle, level)['pDevMode'].Duplex
        #win32api.ShellExecute(0,'print',file_path,'.','/route',0)
        shell.ShellExecuteEx(fmask = win32com.shell.shellcon.SEE_MASK_NOASYNC, lpVerb='print', lpFile=file_path, lpParameters=name)


    win32print.ClosePrinter(handle)
    print("-----DONE FOLDEFR-------------")

print("--------DONE PRINTING-------")
```

Comment: What is your question? It doesn't look to me like it is about printing. I suspect you meant to ask how to resolve `NameError: name 'win32com' is not defined`.

Comment: Both of your questions are right. I want to print pdf files in sequencing order. So I used this win32api . Shellexecute method is printing documents but maintaining order , I want order so I followed one solution where he said use shellexecuteex which will wait till printing current document. So I can get sequence but when I followed that solution got  NameError: name 'win32com' is not defined this error